# How to set usbasp programmer port in avrdude on raspberry pi?

Tags: raspbian, avr, avrdude

I have Raspberry Pi 3 B+ with Raspbian. 
I connected several USBASP programmers to usb ports of Paspberry.
My question is:
How to set correct usb port in command line parameters of avrdude?

In avrdude documentation i found paragraph:

> Problem: Multiple USBasp or USBtinyISP programmers connected simultaneously are not found.
>   Solution: The USBtinyISP code supports distinguishing multiple programmers based on their bus:device connection tuple that describes their place in the USB hierarchy on a specific host. This tuple can be added to the -P usb option, similar to adding a serial number on other USB-based programmers.
>   The actual naming convention for the bus and device names is operating-system dependant; AVRDUDE will print out what it found on the bus when running it with (at least) one -v option. By specifying a string that cannot match any existing device (for example, -P usb:xxx), the scan will list all possible candidate devices found on the bus.
>   Examples:
>   avrdude -c usbtiny -p atmega8 -P usb:003:025 (Linux)
>   avrdude -c usbtiny -p atmega8 -P usb:/dev/usb:/dev/ugen1.3 (FreeBSD 8+)

My programmers connected  to addresses 7 and 8:

```
>sudo lsusb
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 16c0:05dc Van Ooijen Technische Informatica shared ID for use with libusb
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 16c0:05dc Van Ooijen Technische Informatica shared ID for use with libusb
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0424:7800 Standard Microsystems Corp.
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:2514 Standard Microsystems Corp. USB 2.0 Hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:2514 Standard Microsystems Corp. USB 2.0 Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I try wrote this commands:
`avrdude -c usbasp -p m328p -P /bus/usb/001/008`
`avrdude -c usbasp -p m328p -P usb:/bus/usb/001/008`
`avrdude -c usbasp -p m328p -P usb:001:008`
`avrdude -c usbasp -p m328p -P usb:/dev/bus/usb/001/008`
`avrdude -c usbasp -p m328p -P /dev/bus/usb/001/008`
But avrdude still used programmer with address 7. (I connected ATmega2560 to programmer with address 7 and ATmega328P to programmer with address 8)

```
avrdude: warning: cannot set sck period. please check for usbasp firmware update.
avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.01s

avrdude: Device signature = 0x1e9801 (probably m2560)
avrdude: Expected signature for ATmega328P is 1E 95 0F
         Double check chip, or use -F to override this check.

avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

Comment: I would have expceted `usb:001:008` to work if the documentation is correct and matches the version of AVRDUDE you are using.  What is the result of running `avrdude -c usbasp -p m328p -P usb:xxx -v` ?  According to the documentation you quoted, that should give a list of USB devices.  Also, what version of AVRDUDE are you using?

Comment: So, version of avrdude is  6.3-20171130.    
  
When i runnig `avrdude -c usbasp -p m328p -P usb:xxx -v`, i get this output:
https://pastebin.com/h8kJtFgL (It's to long to paste it in comment)
There is no list of USB devices(

Comment: I think you are somehow just using a version of AVRDUDE that is too old to have that feature in it.  I was meaning to dig around in the source repository of AVRDUDE to figure out when that feature was added, but maybe you could try that.  If you try it and don't have any luck, let me know.